# Visual Log Viewer for Ruby On Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, rubygems

I have worked previously on Laravel 4 and there is an awesome log viewer tool for it [laravel log viewer](https://github.com/mikemand/logviewer) view [demo](http://logviewer.kmdwebdesigns.com/logviewer)

I'm looking something very similar for Ruby on rails 4.2, if you guys know any good visual logging GEM for Rails 4.2 please let me know..

From code I need to log at different log levels, and this tool should visually organize my logs, thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started https://github.com/shadabahmed/logstasher

As it says

> This gem is heavily inspired from lograge, but it's focused on one
>   thing and one thing only. That's making your logs awesome like this

More here http://www.shadabahmed.com/blog/2013/04/30/logstasher-for-awesome-rails-logging/

Answer (score 5):

Another simpler gem is https://github.com/dieb/browserlog - it just shows your default rails logs, in the browser, with syntax highlighting.

Comment: thanks joshua, but tail -f is better than browserlog and it's not compatible with rails 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Also see:

https://github.com/discourse/logster

We use it in production across thousands of Discourse instances.